# xpath navigation - find element with X attribute and select its parent's sibling's child

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, bots

Okay, the title is kinda complicated. What I'm doing is a facebook bot that's supposed to take input which equals to somebody's Facebook profile link. Then, it looks for an element that has an  pointing to it and does several actions later.

I think that the easiest way to do it would be using selenium's find_element_by_xpath, but the HTML structure is complicated - it looks like

```
     <div>
        <div>
            <a href="what I'm looking for"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="what I need to click"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I point to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the problem correctly, you can solve it with [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="what I\'m looking for"]/following::div[@class="what I need to click"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked after slight modifications. I've never had anything to do with xpath, so it was my first time using it.